# Public, Private or Protected properties?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm writing a Laravel package but I'm having a problem. The package dispatches a job that does something like this:

```
class ExampleJob
{
    protected $exampleProperty;

    function __construct($parameter)
    {
        $this->exampleProperty = $parameter;
    }
}
```

I need to test if this job is dispatched with the right $parameter (this value is retrieved from the database and, depending on the situation, it will be a different value).

According to the docs, Laravel allows to do this:

```
Bus::assertDispatched(ShipOrder::class, function ($job) use ($order) {
    return $job->order->id === $order->id;
});
```

But this means that the $order property needs to be public (in my case I have: protected $exampleProperty;).

Is this a good practice? I mean declaring a class property as public? What about the concept of Encapsulation in OOP?

Any ideas please?

Comment: try to add getter for the property

Comment: like this https://3v4l.org/u1gF4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the magic method __get

```
class ExampleJob
{
    protected $exampleProperty;

    function __construct($parameter)
    {
        $this->exampleProperty = $parameter;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }
}

$exampleJob = new ExampleJob(42);

// echoes 42
echo $exampleJob->exampleProperty;

// gives an error because $exampleProperty is protected.
$exampleJob->exampleProperty = 13;
```

The __get method is called when no public property is found. In this case you just return the protected property $exampleProperty. This makes the property $exampleProperty readable as a public property, but it cannot be set from outside the ExampleJob class.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest! Magic Methods are incredibly helpful, check here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php for more information on Magic Methods.